# How to use light effects in ThreeJS editor on added shapes

Tags: three.js, light

I'm quite new on ThreeJS and I read the documentation and followed a lot of tutorials.

I now know how to interact with objects (transform, mouseover, rotation, computation on positions and scales, etc.), but I struggle handling the light. For the moment my scene has 4 elements I added thanks to the "Add > cube" menu. When I play the scene, everything is animated correctly, but the color remains the same: everything is in the #XXXXXX color I set.
What I would like is to have an effect of light and shadow like this: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial

I think I have put every option like in this page. What did I do wrong? Here is my scene:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.5,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
    },
    "geometries": [
        {
            "uuid": "4346FD85-69A5-4085-B397-3CDEA12FBCA1",
            "type": "BoxBufferGeometry",
            "width": 1.8,
            "height": 1.8,
            "depth": 1.8,
            "widthSegments": 1,
            "heightSegments": 1,
            "depthSegments": 1
        },
        {
            "uuid": "BCF75EF3-3759-4B20-96E1-720C509A3637",
            "type": "SphereBufferGeometry",
            "radius": 1,
            "widthSegments": 8,
            "heightSegments": 6,
            "phiStart": 0,
            "phiLength": 6.283185,
            "thetaStart": 0,
            "thetaLength": 3.141593
        },
        {
            "uuid": "44E67ACB-39CB-4562-9BDE-4DB448366ED0",
            "type": "DodecahedronBufferGeometry",
            "radius": 1.2,
            "detail": 0
        },
        {
            "uuid": "F0338DDF-165A-47ED-A094-2537432A503B",
            "type": "IcosahedronBufferGeometry",
            "radius": 1.5,
            "detail": 0
        }],
    "materials": [
        {
            "uuid": "388DEE89-D57C-4853-A22D-01554B78FF5B",
            "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0,
            "specular": 1118481,
            "shininess": 30,
            "depthFunc": 3,
            "depthTest": true,
            "depthWrite": true,
            "stencilWrite": false,
            "stencilWriteMask": 255,
            "stencilFunc": 519,
            "stencilRef": 0,
            "stencilFuncMask": 255,
            "stencilFail": 7680,
            "stencilZFail": 7680,
            "stencilZPass": 7680
        },
        {
            "uuid": "C9CA005B-89BC-4CD7-A13E-6F18610A2907",
            "type": "MeshStandardMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "roughness": 1,
            "metalness": 0,
            "emissive": 14869218,
            "depthFunc": 3,
            "depthTest": true,
            "depthWrite": true,
            "stencilWrite": false,
            "stencilWriteMask": 255,
            "stencilFunc": 519,
            "stencilRef": 0,
            "stencilFuncMask": 255,
            "stencilFail": 7680,
            "stencilZFail": 7680,
            "stencilZPass": 7680
        },
        {
            "uuid": "B5419D03-751E-421C-980E-3B004191B7A9",
            "type": "MeshStandardMaterial",
            "name": "poly2",
            "color": 16777215,
            "roughness": 1,
            "metalness": 0,
            "emissive": 10658466,
            "depthFunc": 3,
            "depthTest": true,
            "depthWrite": true,
            "stencilWrite": false,
            "stencilWriteMask": 255,
            "stencilFunc": 519,
            "stencilRef": 0,
            "stencilFuncMask": 255,
            "stencilFail": 7680,
            "stencilZFail": 7680,
            "stencilZPass": 7680,
            "skinning": true
        },
        {
            "uuid": "44FC5BB3-405E-4DF1-9018-087E6BCE1DAE",
            "type": "MeshStandardMaterial",
            "name": "poly3",
            "color": 16777215,
            "roughness": 1,
            "metalness": 0,
            "emissive": 7829367,
            "depthFunc": 3,
            "depthTest": true,
            "depthWrite": true,
            "stencilWrite": false,
            "stencilWriteMask": 255,
            "stencilFunc": 519,
            "stencilRef": 0,
            "stencilFuncMask": 255,
            "stencilFail": 7680,
            "stencilZFail": 7680,
            "stencilZPass": 7680,
            "skinning": true
        }],
    "object": {
        "uuid": "70493730-BD58-409F-8879-037628764C76",
        "type": "Scene",
        "name": "Scene",
        "userData": {
            "souris": [],
            "formes": [
                "Box",
                "Icosahedron",
                "Dodecahedron",
                "Sphere"]
        },
        "layers": 1,
        "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-0.04,-5.06,0,1],
        "children": [
            {
                "uuid": "AE0F3376-E0B4-47A2-8EE4-821522A4E7E2",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "name": "Box",
                "userData": {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 7.6,
                        "z": 0
                    },
                    "couleurs": [
                        "FFFFFF",
                        "095256"],
                    "decalage": 0.5
                },
                "layers": 1,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-0.003758,7.6,0.001485,1],
                "geometry": "4346FD85-69A5-4085-B397-3CDEA12FBCA1",
                "material": "388DEE89-D57C-4853-A22D-01554B78FF5B"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "68FBB0DB-A517-45DD-AE8D-E414E2B5730B",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "name": "Sphere",
                "userData": {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 1,
                        "z": 0
                    },
                    "couleurs": [
                        "FFFFFF",
                        "86A873"],
                    "decalage": 0.2
                },
                "layers": 1,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
                "geometry": "BCF75EF3-3759-4B20-96E1-720C509A3637",
                "material": "C9CA005B-89BC-4CD7-A13E-6F18610A2907"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "816269B9-8C50-4C7D-80B0-D688F0FFF6D2",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "name": "Dodecahedron",
                "userData": {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 3,
                        "z": 0
                    },
                    "couleurs": [
                        "FFFFFF",
                        "5AAA95"],
                    "decalage": 0.3
                },
                "layers": 1,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,0,1],
                "geometry": "44E67ACB-39CB-4562-9BDE-4DB448366ED0",
                "material": "B5419D03-751E-421C-980E-3B004191B7A9"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "8A74081A-5E4F-46A5-9F9E-75537641605F",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "name": "Icosahedron",
                "userData": {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 5.4,
                        "z": 0
                    },
                    "couleurs": [
                        "FFFFFF",
                        "087F8C"],
                    "decalage": 0.5
                },
                "layers": 1,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,5.4,0,1],
                "geometry": "F0338DDF-165A-47ED-A094-2537432A503B",
                "material": "44FC5BB3-405E-4DF1-9018-087E6BCE1DAE"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "8666758A-A261-4E55-91DE-6B0B57C2A104",
                "type": "AmbientLight",
                "name": "AmbientLight",
                "layers": 1,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4.700659,1],
                "color": 13355979,
                "intensity": 0.5
            }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `AmbientLight`, which doesn't have light or dark sides. It illuminates every face evenly, as if the light is coming from every direction, giving all your geometries a flat appearance. Try using something more exciting, like `DirectionalLight`, `Spotlight`, or `HemisphereLight` to get some shading variation. You could spend some time playing with different lights and reading the docs to see how each light behaves differently. [See here to read about AmbientLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/AmbientLight).

The second issue is that you're modifying [the `.emissive` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.emissive) of the material. Adding an emissive color means it will ignore lights, and will just glow on its own. That's why you're getting such flat gray colors. Try instead changing its `.color` property, which will interact more naturally with the light.

See below, I added a `DirectionalLight`, removed `.emissive`, and added different `.color`s to each shape:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly the answer I needed. I see it more clearly now, thank you for enlightening me :D